# How to get quiz game questions to show when button is clicked in Unity?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a quiz game with four buttons for the answers and the questions are stored in an array. The letters are supposed to print out one at a time and after the first 3 indexes are shown then only when a button on the screen is pressed should the next index show.

So far I can only seem to get the first 3 indexes to show, but I am not sure how to get the buttons to trigger the next question in the array to show.

My code is:

```
public GameObject button1;
public GameObject button2;
public GameObject button3;
public GameObject button4;
public float letterPause = 0.05f;
public float sentencePause = 2.0f;
string[] strArray = new string[13];
int i;
int count = 3;
int score;
bool nextQuestion = false;

void Start () {
    strArray[0] = "Hello and welcome!";
    strArray[1] = "This 11 question quiz is going to test your knowledge";
    strArray[2] = "Question 1";
    strArray[3] = "Question 2";
    strArray[4] = "Question 3";
    strArray[5] = "Question 4";
    strArray[6] = "Question 5";
    strArray[7] = "Question 6";
    strArray[8] = "Question 7";
    strArray[9] = "Question 8";
    strArray[10] = "Question 9";
    strArray[11] = "Question 10";
    strArray[12] = "Question 11";
    StartCoroutine (TypeText ());
}

IEnumerator TypeText () {
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        foreach (char letter in strArray[i].ToCharArray()) {

            gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text += letter;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (letterPause);
        }

        if (i != count - 1) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (sentencePause);
        gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "";
        }
    }
    StartCoroutine (TypeText2 ());
}

IEnumerator TypeText2 () {
    while (nextQuestion == true) {
        for (i = 3; i < strArray.Length; i++) {
            foreach (char letter in strArray[i].ToCharArray()) {

                gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text += letter;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds (letterPause);
            }

            gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "";
        }
    }
}

public void OnClickButton1() {
    button1.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "";
    button2.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "";
    button3.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "";
    button4.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "";
    nextQuestion = true;

}

public void OnClickButton2() {
    button1.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "";
    button2.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "";
    button3.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "";
    button4.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "";
    nextQuestion = true;
}

public void OnClickButton3() {
    button1.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "";
    button2.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "";
    button3.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "";
    button4.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "";
    nextQuestion = true;
}

public void OnClickButton4() {
    button1.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "";
    button2.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "";
    button3.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "";
    button4.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "";
    nextQuestion = true;
}
```

Comment: What GUI system are you using to create the buttons? If it's the new Unity UI system, just create a public method on this monobehaviour and link it in the button's properties.

Comment: I am using the new Unity UI system, but I'm not sure what you mean when you say link it to the button's properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your second coroutine is not correct. I am using **`count`** variable as position of question in array to ask and iterate using it.

This is the solution:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class QuizScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject button1;
    public GameObject button2;
    public GameObject button3;
    public GameObject button4;
    public float letterPause = 0.05f;
    public float sentencePause = 2.0f;
    string[] strArray = new string[13];
    int i;
    int count = 3;
    int score;
    bool nextQuestion = false;

void Start () {
    strArray[0] = "Hello and welcome!";
    strArray[1] = "This 11 question quiz is going to test your knowledge";
    strArray[2] = "Question 1";
    strArray[3] = "Question 2";
    strArray[4] = "Question 3";
    strArray[5] = "Question 4";
    strArray[6] = "Question 5";
    strArray[7] = "Question 6";
    strArray[8] = "Question 7";
    strArray[9] = "Question 8";
    strArray[10] = "Question 9";
    strArray[11] = "Question 10";
    strArray[12] = "Question 11";
    StartCoroutine (TypeText ());
}

IEnumerator TypeText () {
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        foreach (char letter in strArray[i].ToCharArray()) {

            gameObject.GetComponent<text> ().text += letter;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (letterPause);
        }

        if (i != count - 1) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (sentencePause);
            gameObject.GetComponent<text> ().text = "";
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator TypeText2 () {
    gameObject.GetComponent<text> ().text = "";
    if(count > strArray.Length - 1) {
        //Winninng or loosing condition 
    } else {            
        //Show the next question
        foreach (char letter in strArray[count - 1].ToCharArray()) {    
            gameObject.GetComponent<text> ().text += letter;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (letterPause);
        }
    }
}

public void OnClickButton1() {
    button1.GetComponent<text> ().text = "";
    button2.GetComponent<text> ().text = "";
    button3.GetComponent<text> ().text = "";
    button4.GetComponent<text> ().text = "";
    count++;
    StartCoroutine (TypeText2 ());
}

public void OnClickButton2() {
    button1.GetComponent<text> ().text = "";
    button2.GetComponent<text> ().text = "";
    button3.GetComponent<text> ().text = "";
    button4.GetComponent<text> ().text = "";
    count++;
    StartCoroutine (TypeText2 ());
}

public void OnClickButton3() {
    button1.GetComponent<text> ().text = "";
    button2.GetComponent<text> ().text = "";
    button3.GetComponent<text> ().text = "";
    button4.GetComponent<text> ().text = "";
    count++;
    StartCoroutine (TypeText2 ());
}

public void OnClickButton4() {
    button1.GetComponent<text> ().text = "";
    button2.GetComponent<text> ().text = "";
    button3.GetComponent<text> ().text = "";
    button4.GetComponent<text> ().text = "";
    count++;
    StartCoroutine (TypeText2 ());
    }
}
```

You can further optimise your script by createing values to store the components which you are using frequently.
Like

```
button1.GetComponent<text> ();
```

you can store it in variable

```
text button1Text = button1.GetComponent<text> ();
```

and use it using

```
button1Text.text = "";
```

instead of finding the component everytime.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed my second coroutine to yours and it caused the `strArray[2]` to repeat twice so I had to change the first coroutine's condition to `for (i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)` and not it only shows once. However, I am not sure I understand what to put in the if loop where you put winning or losing condition because I want the next question to show if any of the buttons are clicked.

Comment: My mistake.. I should have mentioned about other changes in code your main code. In this code instead of starting in the second coroutine in first it is being called on every answer click. The click increases the question counter and starts displaying next question. Just use the entire code instead of using the coroutine. That should work for your game. And the if loop is for when your player has answered all 11 question what should be done there; Like the complete score screen with retry and exit option as your game is over.